Novel mentioning a talk between Conan Doyle and Oscar Wilde and a beast of Dartmoor
I recall to have read a book in which there is a scene where Sir Arthur Conan Doyle and Oscar Wilde are talking to each other at a kind of dinner party, as Wilde advises Doyle to make Holmes more reserved than he is in A Study in Scarlet. "Do not make him 'burst out in laughter'", this quote I do remember. I also recall it mentioning a society dedicated to the research of the novels concerning Sherlock Holmes. A man who is part of said group works together with the protagonists. The book itself took place in modern times, the talk between the two authors was in a flashback or a letter of sorts. I also vaguely remember it containing the beast of Dartmoor which, in the plot of the book (being in modern times), is real and said to have inspired Doyle to write The Hound of the Baskervilles, as he was deeply disturbed by seeing it for himself. I am not entirely sure about this last part being in the same book but it does seem very likely.

I've corrected the spelling of dartmoor. Apologies, english is not my native language.

This might be The Formula for Murder by Carol McCleary. From the publisher’s blurb:

Joined by Oscar Wilde, fleeing a sex scandal, and Arthur Conan Doyle, pursuing a legendary beast of the moors, Nellie [Bly] struggles to stay alive as she hunts down a scientist who is trying to recreate in a test tube the work of God.

If this is right, some of the details have been misremembered. There doesn’t seem to be a scene in which Doyle and Wilde discuss the Holmes stories (although Doyle does get a telegram from Wilde in chapter 43). Instead, it is H. G. Wells who tells Doyle that he enjoyed A Study in Scarlet (chapter 44).

I'm afraid this isn't it. I will remembered just a little bit more and will try to edit my question accordingly. Thanks though
